# Insert a hyperlink with named anchor (#) into ms word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I try to insert a hyperlink into a ms word file, and the hyperlike links to a bookmark in another word file.
since I already know the path of the word file, which contains the bookmark. so I want to combine the path and the bookmark name(namely: "path" +"#"+ "bookmark_name") as the hyperlink in word file. Because in ms word, the hyperlink plus a "#" symbol and followed by a bookmark name will create a link to the bookmark.

My problme is, when I write "#" as a string in my code, run my code. The "#" symbol will not be correctly written into the word file, it will be changed to a bar symbol "-". How can I cope with it?

here's the code:

the "#" symbol here will be changed,

```
string test_file_Path = created_folder + "\\test2.docx" + "#testsbookmark";
```

but in `MessageBox.Show(linkAddr.ToString());` it shows still correct.

```
public void AddContent(string filePath)
{
        try
        {

            Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            // Word Interface
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application WordApp = new Word.Application();
            WordApp.Visible = true;
            object filename = filePath;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            //
            WordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;

            //
            WordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 15f;
            //
            //WordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para;
            para = WordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
            //
            para.Range.Text = "This is paragraph 1";
            //para.Range.Font.Bold = 2;
            //para.Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorRed;
            //para.Range.Font.Italic = 2;
            para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            para.Range.Text = "This is paragraph 2";
            para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            //insert Hyperlink
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection mySelection = WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection;
            mySelection.Start = 9999;
            mySelection.End = 9999;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range myRange = mySelection.Range;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlinks myLinks = WordDoc.Hyperlinks;
            string test_file_Path = created_folder + "\\test2.docx" + "#testsbookmark";
            object linkAddr = test_file_Path;
            MessageBox.Show(linkAddr.ToString());
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink myLink = myLinks.Add(myRange, ref linkAddr,
                ref oMissing);
            WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertAfter("\n");

            //
            WordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = "Created：" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            WordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

            //
            WordDoc.Save();
            WordDoc.Close(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            WordApp.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            //return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            //return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: `Steven` to create a Hyper link you need to do something like the following
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink myLinks = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink)` then to show or display the link do something like this `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range currentRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;`
`currentRange.Hyperlinks.Add(currentRange, "http://www.Stackoverflow.com.");` for example

Comment: @bibadiak ,Hi, thanks for your kindly help. That was posted by me as well ;)

Comment: @iTS .... Thanks for your code! The line "para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();" helped me insert a second link. I did not realize you had to advance the paragraph.

Comment: @KevinMoore  glad, it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked the same question in MSDN, and find an answer, that solve my question. So I repost it here. it is answered by Peter Jamieson.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7df1f959-cda5-42ab-9ede-de058ceafb2d/insert-a-hyperlink-with-named-anchor-into-ms-word

"As far as I know, the way to do this in Word is to insert a hyperlink that looks like this:

{ HYPERLINK "the URL of the document" \l "the bookmark name" }

which you should be able to do using something like this:"

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlinks myLinks = WordDoc.Hyperlinks;
string test_file_Path = created_folder + "\\test2.docx";
object linkAddr = test_file_Path;
string test_bookmark = "testsbookmark";
object linkSubAddr = test_bookmark;
// you may need more parameters here
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink myLink = myLinks.Add(myRange, ref linkAddr, ref linkSubAddr);
WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertAfter("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace the hash with `%23`  Which is a url encoded `#`

Like this:

```
string test_file_Path = created_folder + "\test2.docx" + "%23testsbookmark";
```

Comment: hi @eidsonator , thanks for your reply, I tryed to replace "#" with "%23", as you showed above, but it doesn't work for me, the hyperlink changed to " Desktop\1l\2l\3l\test2.docx%23testsbookmark ".